# Javascript public variable/methods

Tags: javascript, oop

I have JavaScript code as below;

```
var foo = (function() {
    //Private vars
    var a = 1;

    return {
        //Public vars/methods
        a: a,
        changeVar: function () {
            a = 2;
        }
    }
})();
```

Now I am not sure how the syntax for public vars/methods works ?
Could you please corelate how just "returning" the vars/methods makes them as public ?

Thank you.

Comment: You're not making the declared variable `a` public.  You're returning an object with a property of the same name, and you've set it to the same value.  When you `changeVar`, you're changing the property, not the original variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the variable `foo` is actually the value returned by this function. Notice on the last line, the `()`, indicating that this function is evaluated immediately. By evaluating a function and assigning its return value to a variable, you are able to hide variables inside a local (function) scope, such that they are not accessible outside that scope. Only members on the returned object are accessible, but because any functions inside form a closure with their outer scope, you can still use local (hidden) variables.

An example of this would be to hide some local state and only allow access to it through a method:

```
var foo = (function() {
    //Private vars
    var a = 1;

    return {
        //Public methods
        getVar: function () {
            return a;
        },
        setVar: function (val) {
            a = val;
        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you've returned an object in the anonymous function, which means that the object is assigned to `foo`. So you can access the object's properties like `foo.a` or `foo.changeVar`, but you can continue to let the private variables exist, within the function's scope. Can't help much without a more specific question.

Comment: Thx a lot...COuld you please clarify on the 2nd part...when u say "but you can continue to let the private variables exist, within the function's scope"

Comment: Could you please see the above question ?